# No data returned on URL request - Java

Tags: java, html, url

When I run this Java program...

```
        url = new URL("http://www.microsoft.com");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        br.close();
```

I get no returned data.  Using the address www.stackexchange.com returns some HTML, but not the full HTML as I would see in a web browser.  Can someone explain what is happening here?

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that any js-generated html will not show up. Also, some websites require an user agent to be set in order to return data.

Comment: is there a way to force js-generated code to show?

Comment: Not with `URLConnection`, you need to use a browser library

Answer (score 0):

What you see in a browser is a result of multiple calls to the server. In the first call the top level html is loaded. Browser parses the same and make multiple calls back to the server to get other resources like js, css, images etc.

the js, css etc are applied. This in turn may cause more data to be loaded from server and the html updated. So what you see being rendered on the browser is a result of multiple calls. I am assuming you are not planning to write a browser implementation.

This explains why you see partial result in case of stackoverflow.com. You are just getting the barebone html page.

Now for microsoft.com, try loading the page in a browser. Capture all the headers that was sent in the first request. Use the same headers in your java code. You should see some result though not the full result as explained before.